# Where does message "Message Filter dropping message" comes from

Tags: ros2, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to debug find the root cause that generate this kind of error messages:

```
[planner_server-17] [INFO] [1667918874.743278206] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_merged' at time 1667918874.441 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
```

But I could not find in the code for Humble of the whole [nav2 repo](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/humble) nor the [message_filters](https://github.com/ros2/message_filters/tree/humble) any code printing this message, by CTRL+F its keywords like "earlier", "for reason", "Message Filter dropping message"...

Where does this message comes from ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409132/where-does-message-%22message-filter-dropping-message%22-comes-from/) by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2022-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's from `tf2_ros::MessageFilter`, not `message_filters` itself (that's a different package, different class).

Specifically, [here](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/53b782b5e873966369d6b70083fdc3e353a0ad51/tf2_ros/include/tf2_ros/message_filter.h#L700-L710).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0